# Emacs: How change matching color for command "helm-grep-do-git-grep"?

Tags: emacs

Windows 7, Emacs 25.1, Helm package

My **helm-grep-do-git-grep** command screenshot:
[image]

I want to change match text color (dark red) to another (e.g. green).

I try to find in **helm-grep-face**, but not found.
[image]

So how I can change this face color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I change "*d:\Programs\emacs\ .gitconfig*".

Add section:

```
[color "grep"] 
  match = black yellow
```

And now match text color has foreground color = black, and bakground color = yellow

Comment: Thank you, I thought this was a work around but it's the optimized solution.. 
So the color match can be done in the backend (git) or elisp (at helm) and backend coloring is fast and that's why the library forces us to use this configuration..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using, you are looking for either of the following:

```
(defface helm-git-grep-match
  '((default (:inherit helm-match)))
  "Face used to highlight git-grep(1) matches."
:group 'helm-git-grep-faces)
```

or

```
(defface helm-grep-match
  '((((background light)) :foreground "#b00000")
    (((background dark))  :foreground "gold1"))
  "Face used to highlight grep matches."
  :group 'helm-grep-faces)
```

Accordingly, you'll be able to change the color by calling `M-x` `customize-group` `helm-grep-faces` (or `helm-git-grep-faces`).

Comment: I try 2 variants, but it NOT help. I need change foreground for command "helm-grep-do-git-grep" (mathing text color)

Comment: it's inheriting from `helm-match`. Did you try changing that too?

Comment: I change "helm match face" and "helm match item" - but is not help

Comment: I found solution. I change "d:\Programs\emacs\ .gitconfig". Add: [color "grep"]
  match = black yellow

And now match text color has foreground color = black, and bakground color = yellow

Comment: Great. You should add your solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: `helm-match` exists rather than `helm-grep-match`